# Django Test what form a formset uses

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-forms, django-unittest

If I have a form like:

```
class MyForm(modelForm):
    # Form stuff
```

And a formset like:

```
MyFormSet = modelformset_factory(
    MyModel,
    form=MyForm,
    max_num=6,
    validate_max=True,
)
```

Is there a way to test that `form=MyForm`?

```
def test_formset(self):

    formset = MyFormSet()

    self.assertEqual(formset.max_num, 6)
    self.assertTrue(formset.validate_max)
    # Tried this but it didn't work
    self.assertIsInstance(formset.form, MyForm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `formset.form` will be a subclass of `MyForm` class, not instance of it, so `assertIsInstance` will not work. You can check it simply using:

```
def test_formset(self):

    formset = MyFormSet()
    self.assertTrue(issubclass(formset.form, MyForm))
```

for `formset_factory` and when you don't want to allow any subclass of `MyForm` to be provided, this will also work (as `formset_factory` won't modify your form class):

```
def test_formset(self):

    formset = MyFormSet()
    self.assertEquals(formset.form, MyForm)
```

Comment: The first one actually did not work, but the second one did.

Comment: Yeah, for `modelformset_factory` django is creating subclass from provided form. I've adjusted my answer.